# JDBC Drill dependency issues

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, apache-drill

Creating a new project with just the drill jdbc dependency in POM, gives a error saying Could not transfer artifact net.hydromatic:optiq-avatica:pom:0.9-drill-r20 from/to

Should i change anything in settings for this to compile i

I created a new project and adding JDBC dependency in POM.

I tried to compile and i get this error.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
        <artifactId>drill-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Unclear. What does "creating a new project" means? What are you doing precisely? What is outputting this error? What is the complete and exact error message?

Comment: That looks like a network problem. maven cannot connect to download the packages. Try again later and check your network settings.

Comment: I used 1.6.0 its working perfect for me from many days

Answer (score 0):

It seems like network issue bacause I did not find any issue using this jar.

As a workaround, you can add `drill-jdbc-all-1.4.0.jar` located at `<drill_directory>/jars/jdbc-driver` to your project. It includes all the dependent jars.